# remove an element ad replac the other items in this array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array of size say 10, when the array is full and i need to put a new item, i want that program remove the first/oldest item and move the other items one step and the new item should be placed in place [9] and so on.

it sounds like que.

What the best solution for this? I have thout about to create a new array and copy all items form the old array without the element i want to remove !

Any suggestion ?

```
  ArrayList<int> arr = new ArrayList<int> ;
```

Comment: can't you simply use `java.util.Queue` implementation?

Comment: @sanbhat I think he wants a circular queue. AFAIK `java.util.Queue` can't specify a max size?

Comment: exact, i dont wont an open arraylist, it should be an array with size 10

Answer (score 0):

You could use a util.Queue implementation or simply hard code a replacement using

```
 arr.set(index, value)
```

this replaces the specified index with your new value.

Comment: the arra is {1,2,3,4,5,2,1,9}  then i remove the first element witch is  9, the new array is {1,2,3,4,5,2,1}  Noew i add 6  then the new array is {6,1,23,4,5,2,1,9} ,  so how to impelement movment of the elements

Comment: If i understand right (apologies if not and I'm giving you useless advice) you could simple remove the value;

String itemRemove = arr.remove(0);

and re-add it;

arr.add(9, itemRemoved);

Comment: The new element shouldnt replace 9.But the all the items should be replaced upp

Comment: By replaced up do you mean index or value ?